# Check if the length of the range divided by range element has no division remainder

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, rounding, division

The code below shall show a specific comment if the number of elements in the array isn't integer-type number.
It works for `dr=0.5` but not for `dr=0.1` because `print (4%0.1)` returns `0.09999999999999978` instead of `0`.

How can I change the code to get `4%0.1==0`?

```
import math

limits_real=(-2,2)
dr=0.1

if (limits_real[1]-limits_real[0])%dr!=0:
    print ('Inapropriate limits or elements')
```

Comment: try to use math.fmod()

Comment: try int((limits_real[1]-limits_real[0])%dr)!=0

Comment: `the number of elements in the array isn't integer-type number` - a little confusing: how can the **number of elements** in an *array* (you  are using a tuple) be something other than an int... `not isinstance(len(limits_real),int)`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works for dr=0.5 but not for dr=0.1 because print (4%0.1) returns 0.09999999999999978 instead of 0.

Because floating point numbers have limitations that every programmer should know, see this:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

As showed at the end of above documentation, you can use `decimal` module, which works exacly right but is slower than normal floating point arihtmetics:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

limits_real=(-2,2)
dr = Decimal("0.1")

if (limits_real[1] - limits_real[0]) % dr != 0:
    print ('Inapropriate limits or elements')
```

Note that you should use a `str` while constructing the `Decimal` instance, do not use a `float`.

Comment: @wwii You should **not** use an `float` to construct `Decimal`, use `str` as in my code. The reason why your code works wrong is same as why the code without `Decimal` is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I found out only this solution :) At least it works

```py
import math

limits_real=(-2,2)
dr=0.1

if (((limits_real[1] - limits_real[0]) * 1000) % (dr * 1000)) / 1000 != 0:
    print ('Inapropriate limits or elements')
```

Comment: This is not a general solution and still buggy, see the documentation link on my answer.